# EXCEL Custom Format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have column `A` that contains `Phone Numbers`.

I have column `B` that contains the text `Incoming` or `Outgoing`.

I need to highlight column `B` where it contains `Incoming` Only if the number in column `A` is equal to a specific number.

[image: SS]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use conditional formatting with a formula to determine which cells to highlight.

So you will highlight all of column B, and select conditional formatting from the Home tab. Then click new rule.

You want to select the rule type as `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.

You want to use the rule `=AND($A2 = 1, $B2 = "Incoming")`, you can change what `A2` is equal to, and this will highlight the cells in col B that matches a number in A2 and is equal to 'Incoming`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want **Column F** formatted depending on what is in the cells in **Column E** on a row by row basis,

then select Column F and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(E1="111-111-1111",F1="INCOMING")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Adjust the telephone number to suit.

By selecting **Column F** to start with what you have set, applies to a range of **Column F**, hence need to start with Row 1. Since dealing with a single column there is no need for the anchors (`$`).